# Aplicar máscara em uma coluna de tabela HTML com Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angular-6

Como colocar máscara CPF em uma tabela ? Para os inputs utilizei a diretiva ui-cpf-mask, mas preciso colocar em uma célula de tabela.

**codigo:**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of users | async">
            <td>{{user.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{user.cpf}}</td>
 </tr>
```

**Imagem**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo alguma resposta?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic estou recebendo essa mensagem apos implementar sua solução: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'CPF' could not be found ("="user.sexo==1">Masculino</td>
            <td *ngIf="user.sexo==2">Feminino</td>
            <td>{{[ERROR ->]user.cpf | CPF}}</td>
            <td>{{user.nacionalidade}}</td>
            <td>{{user.naturalidade"): ng:///AppModule/UserListComponent.html@25:18
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o erro foi o nome do pipe...tinha colocado em minusculo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie um [PIPE](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes) via comando [CLI Angular](https://cli.angular.io/):

> `ng g pipe CPF`

após terminado esse comando vai ser criado um arquivo com o nome de `cpf.pipe.ts` que o seu valor (`value`) com uma expressão regular possa criar a mascara de CPF da ***seguinte forma***:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'CPF'
})
export class CPFPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, ...args: any[]): any {
    if (value.length === 11) {
      return value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/g, '\$1.\$2.\$3\-\$4');
    }
    return 'error';
  }
}
```

Para utilizar esse `pipe` precisa estar registrado no `app.module.ts` no `array` `declarations`, ***exemplo***:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CPFPipe } from './cpf.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, CPFPipe],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Depois dessa configuração é só utilizar

```
{{ numero_cpf | CPF }}
```

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [generate pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-pipe)
- [pipe](https://angular.io/cli/generate#pipe)
- [Custom pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes)

Answer (score 2):

Se você assim como eu não curte adicionar muita dependência no projeto, dá pra se basear no [pipe de cpf](https://github.com/mariohmol/ng-brazil/blob/master/ng-brazil/src/cpf/pipe.ts) da [ng-brazil](https://github.com/mariohmol/ng-brazil/), instalar o [js-brasil](https://github.com/mariohmol/js-brasil) somente (`npm i js-brasil`) e criar o pipe só pro seu projeto (`ng g pipe cpf`) - isto enquanto o `ng-brazil` não permitir importar somente esse pipe, pelo menos:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { maskBr } from 'js-brasil';

@Pipe({
  name: 'cpf',
})
export class CpfPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(cpfValue: any): string {
    return maskBr.cpf(cpfValue);
  }
}
```

Obs.: lembrar de importar o pipe no módulo que você precisar.

Obs. 2: isto gera um warning:

```sh
WARNING in app\shared\pipes\cpf.pipe.ts depends on 'js-brasil'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie ou utilize um pipe como esse https://github.com/mariohmol/ng-brazil:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of users | async">
            <td>{{user.nome}}</td>
            <td>{{user.cpf  | cpf}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Tentei usar essa lib e achei que adicionou muita dependência no projeto. Não curto essa ideia. Mais fácil só pegar e se basear no pipe de cpf e pronto.